# Having troubles with javascript types

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using a [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Tagging-System-Autocomplete-Amsify-Suggestags.html) for tags in a form and it works well but I am having troubles with the suggestions.

You can have an autocompleter by specifying an attribute

```
suggestions: ['Black','White','Red','Blue','Green','Orange']
```

Thing is, I have to make a call to a servlet to find the keywords to put in there, so I end up with a String that I try to pass to the attribute.

```
var dataFromServlet = "'Black','White','Red','Blue','Green','Orange'";
suggestions: [dataFromServlet]
```

Thing is, now the completer assumes the ENTIRE String is one element.
I have been at this for hours and I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve this seemingly very simple problem. I have tried using arrays, passing JSON from the servlet instead and parsing it, splitting the string and using a loop to rebuild it differently, nothing works. This is driving me crazy, I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.
The plugin documentation does suggest a different method for fetching suggestions via ajax calls, but it ends up calling the ajax method on every single keypress and it lags the whole thing out.

Comment: So convert the string to an array. You are just making one long string in the first index of the array.

Comment: The servlet *should* be written to send you a JSON-encoded array of strings.

Comment: Try this: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Before or after that you probably also want to [replace all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) the single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution, have the backend return a proper JSON object. That way you do not have to worry about your hacky solution breaking because of the data in the string.

If for some problem out of your control you can not make a change to the back end, you can convert to an array by reformatting the string and using JSON.parse

```js
var dataFromServlet = "'Black','White','Red','Blue','Green','Orange'";
var obj = {
  suggestions: JSON.parse("[" + dataFromServlet.replace(/'/g, '"') + "]")
};
console.log(obj.suggestions);
```

Again, this solution is a bandaid, the correct solution is make the back end servlet return proper JSON formatted data.